# Post request through GAE headers issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, http-headers, urllib

I send a POST request from a GAE Flask service to other GAE Flask service

```
try:
    service_url = 'http://localhost:4040/getservice'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Auth-Key': AUTH_KEY,
        'Customer': str(CUSTOMER)
    }

    s = Session()
    req = requests.Request('POST', service_url, data=conf, headers=headers)
    readytogo = req.prepare()

    #del readytogo.headers['Content-Lenght']
    #del readytogo.headers['Host']

    module = s.send(readytogo)

except Exception as e:
    print('error')
    print(e)
    return e
```

But i have this error:

```
Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host', 'Content-Length']
```

If **I delete that header** i have this error in console:

```
error
'content-lenght'
```

and this error in page:

```
An internal error occurred:
'exceptions.KeyError' object is not callable
See logs for full stacktrace.
```

The header Content-Lenght and Host are not supported from GAE!
How can I send a POST request from GAE to other GAE endpoint???

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the statement removing a header, which is what's causing the error:

```
del readytogo.headers['Content-Lenght']
```

instead of

```
del readytogo.headers['Content-Length']
```